# Is it possible to create a custom facebook tab?

Tags: c#, facebook

i would like to create a custom tab with the users facebook profile. I will show the users recent posts compared the friends posts. it will include the post count, avg words per post, etc of the user and the users friends. Is this possible to do in facebook?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you can do that .
facebook provide option for add tab , and by using FQl stream table you can get posts of user (so can do post count & other stuff )but   you can only compare with those  friend who too are user of your app , because for reading stream you need extended  permission